# Python, when override __eq__() in a new Class, strange thing happened

Tags: python

I want to override the **eq** in a new Class A, the code are:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __eq__(self, obj):
...         return True
...     

>>> a = A()

>>> b = A()

>>> L = [0, 0, a, 1]

>>> L.index(a)
0

>>> L.index(0)
0

>>> L.index(100)
2

>>> L.index(1)
2
```

It is hard to understand how did this happened.

Comment: Which part/result do you not understand? You always get True when comparing to `a`.

Comment: why L.index(1) and L.index(100) return 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's logically assume that `index()` works sequentially through the list `L`, from lowest index to highest, stopping when it first encounters a `True` comparison for the element.

```
>>> L.index(a)
```

`a == 0` is the first `True` match, thus matching the first element of `L`.

```
>>> L.index(0)
```

`0 == 0` is the first `True` match, thus matching the first element of `L`.

```
>>> L.index(100)
```

`100 == a` is the first `True` match, thus matching the third element of `L`.

```
>>> L.index(1)
```

`1 == a` is the first `True` match, thus matching the third element of `L`.

Comment: Cool, I understand it. Thx

Comment: `__eq__` has to work both ways, by its nature. Perhaps that confused you (`a == 100` also means `100 == a`).

Comment: @Evert That's incorrect. See [this example](http://pastebin.com/RyjnJcNP) where `x == y` but `y != x`. Equality comparison (using `==`) calls the `__eq__` method of the object on the left. If that fails (in this case `int`'s `__eq__` can't be used to compare object of type `A`) it will call try to call the `__eq__` of the object on the right.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Neat; hadn't realised that, though the `other` argument is a give-away.